# CoreML Model not returning results

Tags: ios, swift, coreml

I am using [this](https://github.com/keplerlab/neuralCreativityServer) CoreML Model to test sketch recognition but it is not returning any results. Here is my code:

```
func predict(){
    guard let image = UIImage(named: "test.png") else{
        print("Image not found")
        return
    }
    do{
        let model = try VNCoreMLModel(for: sketch2().model)
        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: displayPredictions)
        let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cgImage: (image.cgImage!))
        try handler.perform([request])
    }catch{

    }
}

func displayPredictions(request: VNRequest, error: Error?) {

    if let results = request.results as? [VNClassificationObservation]{
        print(results)
    }else{
        print("some error")
    }

}
```

And the `predict()` method is called in `viewDidLoad()`.

When `results()` is printed in `displayPredictions()` it returns the empty array `[]`. I [asked the developer of the model](https://github.com/keplerlab/neuralCreativityServer/issues/1) what format of image the model accepts and he said that it is a 128x128 grayscale, this could be the problem and if so how would I convert the `test.png` file to a 128x128 grayscale. If you have any other ideas about the problem, possibly a problem with the conversion of the model using coremltools or anything else, please let me know. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is it a classification model? What does Core ML say the expected output is (when you open the .mlmodel file in Xcode)? Note that Vision currently does not seem to work with models that are _not_ classifiers.

Comment: Yes, I am fairly certain it is a classifier, the model expects a `Image<Grayscale,128,128>` as input and outputs a `MultiArray<Double>`. So I am guessing that it outputs one of the labels in the [map.txt file](https://github.com/keplerlab/neuralCreativityServer/blob/master/server/caffeModel/map.txt). I think it has something to do with the conversion / output itself and not the input as even when I try with some of the data that the model was trained on it still outputs the empty array.

Comment: If the output is a `MultiArray` then it's not a classifier (in Core ML). A classifier in Core ML returns a dictionary of `String: Double`. When you converted the model, did you specify `class_labels='map.txt'`?

Comment: This was the script I used: ```import coremltools

coreml_model = coremltools.converters.caffe.convert(('sketchANet_full_iter_7500.caffemodel', 'deploy.prototxt'), predicted_feature_name='map.txt', image_input_names='data')
coreml_model.save('sketch2.mlmodel')``` Shoukd I try replace `predicted_feature_name='map.txt'` with `class_labels='map.txt'`? @MatthijsHollemans

Comment: Yes, the `predicted_feature_name` is a bug in the documenttion. It should be `class_labels` instead.

Comment: I am now getting the error `The VNCoreMLTransform request failed` but I think this is unrelated. Should I open a new question? Should I be retrieving something other than `request.results`? Thanks so much for the help so far by the way.

Comment: That sounds like Vision has a problem handling your model or your input data. I would try running your model without Vision first (i.e. create a grayscale CVPixelBuffer of 128x128 pixels and call your model's `prediction(data: pixelBuffer)` function and see what happens).

Comment: Trying this now, is there somewhere else we can talk, possibly on slack? (Not enough reputation to use StackOverFlow chat)

Comment: The https://ios-developers.io slack has a #machine-learning channel.

Comment: Thanks sent a message on there.